# How to create a structured files in Delphi

Tags: file, delphi

I want to create a structured file to store:

Type 1 data as follows:

```
Name: UnicodeString;
ID: Integer;
Content: UnicodeString;
Img: TBitmap;
```

Among its capabilities, I need it to store a lot of records and being able to seek a given record and count the total number of records.

In a different file, I want to store type 2 data as follows:

```
-Name: String;
-BitmapDir
+ Bitmap1: TBitmap;
+ Bitmap2: TBitmap;
+..............: TBitmap;
+ BitmapN: TBitmap;
-Database
+ IniFile: TINIFiles;
```

Do you know any way of creating those files?

I know I can use the library uKBDynamic to create the file as type 2 with sample SimpleStorage but I really don't know about it and how to use it.

Comment: you should think about Streams or XML/JSON or Database (e.g. SQLite/Firebird). what is your favorite?

Comment: Put it in an embedded db

Comment: @user do you need to share this files with other programs/systems?

Comment: Don't roll your own binary formats.  An embedded DB (like SQLite) can be trusted for large volumes of data and is high-performance (nice to have) and reliable (must-ave).  A roll your own binary file is a doorway into a world of hurt. For small interoperable and transparently readable content, use JSON.

Comment: The uKBDynamic unit  you're using as part of https://code.google.com/p/kblib/ looks like it might be deprecated even by its own author.

Comment: Another vote for XML. You will need to encode the Bitmap though as Base64.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Structured Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It is a COM based api that lets you write files that almost embed a complete file system themselves. In that, you could write a list of streams, each containing the data of one of your records.